# How to transmit my jquery result for processing in my codeigniter ocntroller?

Tags: codeigniter-2

Have a good day.

I am doing a select all checkbox to delete selected posts. I am able to get the result in the jquery but I am not sure how to use that result to process in my Codeigniter Controller. Maybe someone can enlighten me. Thanks!

View File:

```
<input class="delete_selection" type="checkbox" name="delete_selection[]" value="1" />
<input class="delete_selection" type="checkbox" name="delete_selection[]" value="2" />
<input class="delete_selection" type="checkbox" name="delete_selection[]" value="3" />

<button id="delete_selected" name="delete_selected" class="btn btn-danger btn-small" value="" onClick="return confirm('Delete selected posts?')"><i class="icon-trash icon-white"> &nbsp; </i> Delete Selected</button>
```

JQuery:

```
    //GET SELECTED POSTS/PAGES FOR DELETION 
$("#delete_selected").click(function(event) {

    /* stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault();

    var values = new Array();

    $.each($('input[name="delete_selection[]"]:checked'), function() {

        var delete_selection = $(this).val()

        console.log(delete_selection);
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
    public function post_delete(){

        //HOW TO GRAB THE RESULT FROM THE JQUERY? 
        //I KNOW IT SHOULD BE IN AJAX BUT NOT QUITE SURE HOW TO DO IT.

        $id = $this->input->post('delete_selection');                  

        for( $i=0; $i<sizeof($id); $i++) :

            $this->posts_model->delete_post_selection($id[$i]);

        endfor;

        $data['message_success']    = $this->session->set_flashdata('message_success', 'You have successfully deleted your selected posts.');
        redirect('admin/posts/posts_list', $data);

}
```

Model:

```
    //MULTIPLE DELETE
function delete_post_selection($id) {

    $this->db->where_in('post_id', $id)->delete('posts');

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your thinking is wrong, the controller isn't gonna 'grab' the values. But javascript is going to post to the controller

Assuming you put your html inside a form you could do something like this:

view:

```
<form action="/post_delete">
<input class="delete_selection" type="checkbox" name="delete_selection[]" value="1" />
<input class="delete_selection" type="checkbox" name="delete_selection[]" value="2" />
<input class="delete_selection" type="checkbox" name="delete_selection[]" value="3" />

<button id="delete_selected" name="delete_selected" class="btn btn-danger btn-small" value=""><i class="icon-trash icon-white"> &nbsp; </i> Delete Selected</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('#delete_selection').click(function(e){
    if(!confirm('Delete?')) return;//ask user if they're sure

    //stop default form submitting from happening because 
    //we'll use ajax
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this).closest('form');//get the parent form
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),//get url to send it to
        type: "POST",
        data: form.serialize(),//get data from the form
        success: function(){
            //do something with success
        }
        error: function(){
            //do something with error
        } 
});
```

And now you can use the data in your controller by accessing $_POST try

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

to see what has been posted

Comment: Hi @xeli, Thanks for the comment. Actually, the values are not coming from a form. In my JS, it gets the values of the selected checkboxes and return the values. Since, I am able to get the values, I would like to use these in the Controller to be passed to my Model for the deletion. I have successfully managed my question but I need the confirmation first before the deletion. My answer will be below. =)

Comment: Since currently I cannot answer my own question, I have pasted my answer here: http://pastebin.com/nBNqA9ci =)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the correct way as it POST repeatedly but does the work so far.

In my JS:

```
    //GET SELECTED POSTS/PAGES FOR DELETION 
$("#delete_selection").click(function(event) {
       if(!confirm('Delete selected posts?')) return false;//ask user if they're sure


    /* stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault();

    $.each($('input[name="delete_selection[]"]:checked'), function() {  

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'post_delete_selection',
          data: 
            { selected: $(this).val() },
          success: function(data){              

            setTimeout(function () {
                window.location.href = window.location.href;
            }, 1000);

            $('#ajax_message').show().html('Successfully deleted.');
          },              
        });             

    }); 
});
```

My Controller:

```
    public function post_delete_selection(){

    $selectedIds = $_POST['selected']; //THIS GRABS THE VALUES FROM THE AJAX
    $this->posts_model->delete_post_selection($selectedIds);         

}
```

My Model:

```
    function delete_post_selection($selectedIds) {

    $this->db->where_in('post_id', $selectedIds)->delete('posts');

    return true;
}
```